# Symbolic link redirects to root folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use mod_rewrite to change the following URL from this

```
example.com/control/service.php?id=1
```

to this

```
example.com/control/service/1
```

But at the moment I reach 'example.com/control/service/1' the URL changes to 'example.com/service/1' skipping the control/ folder and throws an 404.

I have the .htaccess file inside the control/ folder with the following content.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ $1.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^service/([0-9]+)$ service.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure multiviews is turned off, then try adding a base:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /control/
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ $1.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^service/([0-9]+)$ service.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```